# Dartでawaitをasyncが付いてないメソッドで使えない

Tags: 非同期, flutter, dart

※最初の投稿では認識間違いがあったので修正です

以下のようなコードがあって、asyncが付いているメソッドからは`data = await readData()`と書けば待ってくれるのですが、そうでないメソッドだとawaitは使えないとエラーが出ます。
どうしたらasyncが付いてないメソッドでも使えるようにできるでしょう？

```dart
class FileTools{
  Future<Map<String, List<String>>> readData() async {
    if(_file==null) setFile();

    try {
      String data = await _file.readAsString();
      return json.decode(data);
    } catch (e) {
      // If encountering an error, return 0.
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: なぜ, 非同期処理ではない 通常のメソッドに `await`を付けたいのでしょうか？ (付ける意味もないのに)

Comment: 呼び出し先のメソッドにasyncが付いてないという意味ではなく呼び出し元のメソッドでawaitしたいということです。

Comment: いえ, 呼び出す側で `await` 付ける意味を尋ねています。「await したい」とはどんなことを意味してるのでしょう？ 非同期処理でない関数/メソッドは普通に処理が終わるまで戻ってきません

Comment: 非同期処理でない関数から, 非同期関数を呼び出したいという質問なのでしょうか？ 呼び出し元と呼び出される側の関係 … 何の処理から何の処理を呼び出そうとして, どのようになる…を明確にすると質問の意図が伝わりやすいかも

Comment: 例えば例示のメソッドだとreadData()を呼んで取得したデータを利用したいわけですが、awaitしないと非同期なのでデータを読み込む前に処理が実行されnullエラーが起きたりしますよね？

Comment: 質問にはいくつか分かりづらい点があります。分かりやすく直したほうがよい気がします。
・ 関数/メソッドの呼び出し方,なのに片方しかない。提示のコードはどちら側か明確にされていない。
・ **そうでないメソッド** とは, どれと比べ「何が」そうでないのか？(明確とは言えない)
…コードを示すなら, 小さくしかも完結したコードが望ましいでしょう。(呼び出し側, 呼び出される側含む形で)

Answer (score 1):

質問を, ある別の 非同期でない処理の中から, 非同期メソッド `readData()` を呼び出す方法, と判断します

非同期処理は, いくつかのプログラミング言語で `async`/`await` のワードで扱えるようになっています。が, `await` は非同期関数から非同期関数を呼び出す際に用いられ, 通常の関数から呼び出すことは(そのままでは)できません。(`await`なしで呼び出せるが callbackを受け取れない, など, 言語によって違いがある)

Dartや JavaScriptでは, `async`/`await` 導入以前に非同期処理の機能が存在し, それを利用することが可能。
Dartでの非同期処理は `future` と呼ばれるようです。それを使うには

1. `async` と `await` を使う方法
2. `Future` (クラス)の APIを使う方法

後者の `Future` API では, 非同期処理完了の callback 受け付け(？)に `then()`メソッドを指定

```dart
final future = a_method()
future.then((val) => print(val))
```

また, Dartの `Future` APIは, JavaScriptでの `Promise` がそれに当たるので参考にできるかもしれません
【参考】
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

```
doSomething()
.then(result => doSomethingElse(result))
.then(newResult => doThirdThing(newResult))
.then(finalResult => {
  console.log(`Got the final result: ${finalResult}`);
})
.catch(failureCallback);
```